# What is the purpose of master and master=none in an init function in python?

Tags: python, class, python-2.7, python-3.x, tkinter

I would assume the the reason is similar to self which i get.Why is master there? Also, why is it sometimes master and sometimes master = none?

e.g

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.createWidgets()
```

from Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python by John W. Shipman. Also, the doc uses python2 while I will be using python3. Do I need master?
More problems
I tried adding custom arg after master and it said I can't add a non-default arg after a default, how should I fix? doesn't the default arg self have to be first?

```
def __init__(self, master=None,inputDict):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
    self.grid(sticky=tk.N+tk.S+tk.E+tk.W)
    self.createWidgets()
def createWidgets(self,inputDict):
    top=self.winfo_toplevel()
    top.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    top.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
tempDict = {}
for k,v in inputDict.items():
        if 1<=v[0]<=3:
            tempDict[k] = static_keys(*v[1:])
        elif v[0] ==4:
            tempDict[k] = dynamic_keys(*v[1:])
        elif  v[0]==5:
            tempDict[k] = key_labels(*v[1:])
return tempDict
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Application` class is a subclass of `tk.Frame`. The `master` parameter is the parent widget and it is an optional parameter (by default it is `none`) that will be passed to the new instance of `Application` class when it is initialized.

[Take a look here for more info](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/frame.htm).

Comment: It should be called parent. I will except as soon as SO lets me.

Comment: also when calling an init func to do I need to specify a master if the def does not have =0 behind it? what about self?

Comment: @fozbstuios sorry for the late answer... `self` is a pointer to the variable storing the new instance. So in `a=Application()`, self will point to `a`. If `def __init__()` does not have `=None`, the `master` argument will become mandatory

Comment: can i use parent instead of master=None?

Comment: @SandeepPrasadKushwaha If I understood you correctly, you want to put your `Application` object under another parent object that you have, right? In that case just indicate that my doing `master=your_parent_object`